# unregistering broadcast receiver on sms received

Tags: android

The SMS that has been intercepted by my broadcast receiver is being sent to my inbox even though i use abortBroadcast(). This problem arises only when i use unRegisterReceiver(). If i do not unRegister, the abortBroadcast works fine. Any ideas on how to abort and then unregister successfully? Here is the code :

In my main activity, I have declared a broadcast receiver object  :

```
SmsReceiver BR_smsreceiver = null;
```

Then i register the broadcast receiver and send an SMS from within a function in the main activity :

```
public Boolean sendVerificationSms(String number) {
BR_smsreceiver = null;
BR_smsreceiver = new SmsReceiver();
BR_smsreceiver.setMainActivityHandler(this);
IntentFilter fltr_smsreceived = new IntentFilter(
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
registerReceiver(BR_smsreceiver, fltr_smsreceived);

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, "hi", null, null);
}
```

The Broadcast receiver intercepts the SMS and calls a function within the main activity :

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MainActivity main = null;

    void setMainActivityHandler(MainActivity main){
        this.main=main;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle pdusBundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus=(Object[])pdusBundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage messages=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        if(messages.getMessageBody().contains("hi")){
            abortBroadcast();
            main.verifyPhoneNumber("hi");

        }

    }
}
```

The function unregisters the broadcast receiver and does some processing :

```
public void verifyPhoneNumber(String number) {
        unregisterReceiver(BR_smsreceiver);
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that worked is using a delay(even 0 ms worked!) for unregistering :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                unregisterReceiver(BR_smsreceiver);
            }
        },0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        unregisterReceiver(BR_smsreceiver);
    }
```

Comment: This wouldn't serve my purpose as i need to unregister the broadcast receiver after it has been triggered, not after the app has paused.